# send file with object to webapi

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have problem with my project.
I have a table in mssql and it has picaddress as nvarchar and also has id which is unique.
For creating a new object i have to send the name to server to create new id then send image to server and then save the picaddress but i like to send object of table and image both together.

What can i do?

```
BitmapImage s1 = new BitmapImage();
s1.BeginInit();
s1.UriSource = new Uri(openfiledialog.FileName);
s1.EndInit();
image.Source = s1;
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(openfiledialog.FileName));
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = openfiledialog.FileName };
requestContent.Add(fileContent, openfiledialog.FileName, openfiledialog.FileName);
HttpClient cli = new HttpClient();
cli.PostAsync(Ntaban.Api.API_server.Host+ "api/managment/Insert_Product", requestContent);
```

this is my object iud and the image is s1.

Comment: Why not just encapsulate it all in a class, and just pass it?

Comment: whitch prperty can i use for image?